# Spark SQL: java.lang.RuntimeException: [B is not a valid external type for schema of string

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

1. my stack trace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: [B is not a valid external type for schema
>   of string     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.serializefromobject_doConsume_0$(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.mapelements_doConsume_0$(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedRDDBuilder$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.hasNext(InMemoryRelation.scala:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:299)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1165)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:357)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:308)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Problem description:
I want to use spark-sql DataSet write to kafka topic,but met valid external type exception.

I know this is due to the inconsistency between the value and the schema type.

This is my kafka schema:

```
    private static StructType KAFKA_SCHEMA() {
        List<StructField> fs = new ArrayList<>();
        // key|value|topic|partition|offset|timestamp|timestampType
        fs.add(DataTypes.createStructField("key", DataTypes.ByteType, true));// for Binary key schema
        fs.add(DataTypes.createStructField("value", DataTypes.ByteType, true));
        fs.add(DataTypes.createStructField("topic", DataTypes.StringType, true));
        return new StructType(fs.toArray(new StructField[fs.size()]));
    }
```

I try to use DataTypes.BinaryType,same problem.

Please see the  debugging screenshot:

[image]

According to the screenshot, the type and value are one-to-one.

Why did the program report this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

struct streaming only support BinaryType and String

schema should be:

```
        fs.add(DataTypes.createStructField("key", DataTypes.BinaryType, true));
        fs.add(DataTypes.createStructField("value", DataTypes.BinaryType, true));
        fs.add(DataTypes.createStructField("topic", DataTypes.StringType, true));
```